# How to get hashmap key and value in java from another function

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I have a json parse like this

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String contestUrl = "http://api.apps.com/contest";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_ITEM_ID = "id";    
private static final String TAG_URL = "url";    
private static final String TAG_START_DATE = "start_date";    
private static final String TAG_END_DATE = "end_date";   

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray foods = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> foodslist;



}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    foodslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();




 // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();

}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(contestUrl, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                foods = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < foods.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = foods.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_URL);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_START_DATE);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_END_DATE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ITEM_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_URL, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_START_DATE, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_END_DATE, address);

                    String start_date = (String)contact.get(TAG_ITEM_ID);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    foodslist.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I have two function, `onCreate` and `GetContacts`. In the end of `onCreate` it call `GetContacts` and call this json.

My question is, how can I got the `Hashmap` value on `GetContacts` so I can use it on `onCreate`

So far, I got this to get the value of `Hashmap`

`String start_date = (String)contact.get(TAG_ITEM_ID);`

But, its only works on `GetContacts`.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks Before

Comment: not sure, what exactly is the problem here. You are adding the hashmap `contact` to `foodslist`. What type is `foodslist`? And why can't you return it or make it class member if you access it from more than one method in the class? Please post full code or at least method APIs with brief descriptions to bring more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways:

**Way-1:**
Create instance variable (class-level) of HashMap contact and then you can use it anywhere within class inclusing onCreate and getContacts method.

```
package stackoverflow.q_25034927;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PassVariable {
    private static Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void onCreate() {
        //populate contact object as per your logic
        getContacts();
    }

    private void getContacts() {
        //Use contact object directly which was pre-populby onCreate method.
    }
}
```

**Way-2:**
Pass map to the getContacts() method:

```
package stackoverflow.q_25034927;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PassVariable {

    public void onCreate() {
        final Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //populate contact object as per your logic.
        getContacts(contact);
    }

    private void getContacts(Map<String, String> contact) {
        //Use contact object which is passed as argument.
    }
}
```

---

On other side, please use cameCasing while naming Java methods or variables. GetContacts is not right, make it getContacts.

For email and address fields, using TAG_START_DATE and TAG_END_DATE is no fun. :-)

```
String email = c.getString(TAG_START_DATE);
String address = c.getString(TAG_END_DATE);
```

---

To answer about #3 below, variable s is not accessible in NotInner class:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {
    static String s = "";
}

class NotInner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(s); //Compilation error: s cannot be resolved to a variable
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. '}' brace before onActivityCreated(Bundle) method generates compile time error. ||  2. foodslist as instance variable is perfectly alright.  ||  3. GetContacts class should be within SecondFragment class as inner class.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more about the thrid point? I don't really understand it

Comment: Please check my edited answer, you need inner class to access 'foodslist' variable inside GetContacts.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
List<Map<String,String>> foodslist = ...;
```

which is filled in the loop.

To get at individual values, iterate:

```
for( Map<String,String> item: foodslist ){
   String id = item.get(TAG_ITEM_ID);
   String name = item.get(TAG_URL);
   String email = item.get(TAG_START_DATE);
   String address = item.get(TAG_END_DATE);
}
```

Or you write a method for the class where you keep foodslist:

```
String getAttr( int i, String tag ){
    return foodslist.get(i).get(tag);
}
```

and you can call

```
String id = xxx.getAttr( i, TAG_ITEM_ID );
```

Comment: can you check my question? I edit my code. But if I see from your answer, what I miss it the for loop inside the `onCreate`? Am I right

Answer (score 0):

So return the data ...

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getContacts() {
if (foodslist != null && foodslist.isEmpty()) {
    return foodslist;
}
foodslist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
try {

foods = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

// looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < foods.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject c = foods.getJSONObject(i);

   String id = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);
   String name = c.getString(TAG_URL);
   String email = c.getString(TAG_START_DATE);
   String address = c.getString(TAG_END_DATE);

   // tmp hashmap for single contact
   HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

   // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
   contact.put(TAG_ITEM_ID, id);
   contact.put(TAG_URL, name);
   contact.put(TAG_START_DATE, email);
   contact.put(TAG_END_DATE, address);

   // adding contact to contact list
   foodslist.add(contact);
}
return foodslist;
}
```

Though I'm not sure why that variable is called foodslist if it's supposed to contain contacts.